# Prompt for user input and store the data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I just started iOS development, and now I'm stuck. I have a table cell, where the user cann see data. Next to it, there are two buttons. One to delete, one to edit. The edit part is where I'm stuck. I have a label field. When the user clicks on the edit button a prompt should come where the user can type in data. I already found something to do it. But there's no save button and I don't know how I could then save the variable to an `NSString`

```
UIAlertView * alert     = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name der neuen Liste" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle    = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

I currently have this. lNow a prompt pops up, where I can write something, but not save. I just can press cancel afterwards. How do I work with user input in iOS? I don't want to use the label as an `UITextField` since it has to be clickable to perform another action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)noteInput
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"input"
                                                    message:@"input"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];

    [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alertView show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UITextField *noteText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSString *note = noteText.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 more minutes. Otherwise I would have already ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `Save` button in `otherButtonTitles`. Then, in your `UIAlertViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
         // Save button pressed
    }
}
```